# Override location directives in nginx not working

Tags: nginx

I want to override the permissions to `/folder/script.php` and have the following rules:

```
 location ^~ /folder/script.php{
    allow all;
  }              #shouldn't ^this one with ^~ override the others?

 location ~ /folder/(.+)\.php$ {
  deny all;
  return 404;
  allow 127.0.0.1;
 }

  location ~ ^/folder {
    return 404;
  }

location / {

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then trigger 404
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        server_name_in_redirect off;        

}

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        #fastcgi_pass /tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass /var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

           fastcgi_index index.php;  

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $root_folder$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $root_folder;

        # send bad requests
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

but whenever I access admin.php I still get a 404 error and/or the script.php file is served to download, not interpreted. Could someone explain me why? Tyvm

Comment: `nginx` cannot interpret PHP. It sends the file to an upstream interpreter like `php-fpm`. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) for an example.

Comment: @RichardSmith i know. I was using a figure of speech. All other my PHP files work well. So, what exactly might be wrong?

Comment: So you must have a `location` container in your `nginx` configuration file which sends `.php` URIs to an upstream interpreter. Your `location ^~ /folder/script.php` block will take precedence and instructs `nginx` to serve the file as a download.

Comment: @RichardSmith correct, already pulled it above that, doesn't present the file to download but unfortunately still does not allow access to the folder script...

Comment: Location block order is irrelevant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith but my problem should be within the code displayed here... Can't you really figure anything by this?

Comment: Edit your question and add the contents of the enclosing `server` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith done, please do help now :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands to execute a php script are:

```
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $root_folder$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $root_folder;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include fastcgi_params;
```

I'm not sure where you define `$root_folder`, normally `$document_root` is used. The above (or similar) *code* must appear in each and every `location` block that is expected to execute php scripts.

So your configuration should look something like this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  server_name_in_redirect off;
}

location ^~ /folder { deny all; }

location = /folder/script.php {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $root_folder$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $root_folder;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $root_folder$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $root_folder;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I have taken the liberty of simplifying your configuration a little. It seems that only the file `/folder/script.php` is executable within the `/folder` hierarchy, so an exact match (`location =`) is used, and `/folder` is denied. The `allow 127.0.0.1;` does nothing as it comes after the `deny all`.

As you can see, the `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` directive must appear in any location container that directly handles php code. I would put some or all of these directives into a separate file and use `include` to pull them in at each location.

The rest of the directives have been copied across from your question, but I don't know if they are required here.

Comment: Wow richard, **thank you so much**, this is so F amazing. I have just one question though: why exactly do I need to duplicate the php redirect code if all the folder logic was perfect in *theory* before? Didn't the last `location ~ \.php$ {` apply to everything?

Comment: `location ~ \.php$` only applies to php files that don't match any other `location` block with higher precedence. So, `location ~ /folder/(.+)\.php$` and `location ~ ^/folder` have higher precedence, but are not required to actually execute the script. `location ^~ /folder/script.php` has both higher precedence **and** is expected to execute the script, and as such *also* required the `fastcgi_pass` configuration within the block. Hope that helps.

Comment: that does make sense. Thank you a whole lot again Richard :)